# How do I use parameter epsabs in scipy.integrate.quad in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, precision, numerical-integration, quad

I am trying to compute the integrals more precise by specifying the parameter `epsabs` for `scipy.integrate.quad`, say we are integrating the function *sin(x) / x^2* from 1e-16 to 1.0

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy

integrand = lambda x: numpy.sin(x) / x ** 2
integral = quad(integrand, 1e-16, 1.0)
```

This gives us

```sh
(36.760078801255595, 0.01091187908038005)
```

To make the results more precise, we specify the *absolute error tolerance* by `epsabs`

```py
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy

integrand = lambda x: numpy.sin(x) / x ** 2
integral = quad(integrand, 1e-16, 1.0, epsabs = 1e-4)
```

The result is exactly the same and the error is still as large as 0.0109! Am I understanding the parameter `epsabs` wrong? What should I do differently to increase the precision of integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to scipy manual [quad function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad) has `limit` argument to specify

> An upper bound on the number of subintervals used in the adaptive algorithm.

By default the value of `limit` is 50. 
You code return warning message

> quadpack.py:364: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of
>   subdivisions (50) has been achieved.   If increasing the limit yields
>   no improvement it is advised to analyze   the integrand in order to
>   determine the difficulties.  If the position of a   local difficulty
>   can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will   probably
>   gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator   on
>   the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
>   warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)

You have to change `limit` argument, i.e.:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy

integrand = lambda x: numpy.sin(x) / x ** 2
print(quad(integrand, 1e-16, 1.0, epsabs = 1e-4, limit=100))
```

Output:

> (36.7600787611414, 3.635057215414274e-05)

There is no warning message in output. Number of subdivisions is under 100 and `quad` got required accuracy.

Comment: Can we do it similarly with nquad?